# Change location of repositories gitosis

Tags: centos, git

I installed gitosis on my CentOS box last week. I'm really happy with how it works and how simple it is to use.

I've run into a small problem though. Because gitosis is installed under a new user account *git* all of the install files and the repositories are held in the git user's directory which is on the system drive.

I only have a limited amount of space available on my system drive, so would like to move the repository directory to a second drive on this machine.

Short of copying them over and creating a symlink to the new location, I can't see a way to achieve this.

Has anyone managed to do this successfully?

Cheers

T

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a symbolic link to do this.

Seems to work without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and change home dir

```
sudo cp -R /home/git/ /new/path
sudo usermod -d /tmp root
```